# Notify when a background request has finished swift

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I'm sending a request to my backend server and I need to know the right way to notify my main thread the response. I'm using the NSNotificationCenter for this task but this not work sometimes and has some delay when it works because when I'm debugging I can see when the console prints the result but then a  few secs later the corresponding alert to appear.

Here is my request:

```
    let request1 = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: serverID)!)
    request1.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    for key in parameters.keys{
        request1.addValue(parameters[key] as String!, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
    }

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request1) {
        data, response1, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("request1Error", object: self)
            return
        }
        else {
            let httpResponse = response1 as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let headers = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as NSDictionary
            let sucess: AnyObject? = headers.objectForKey("UserId")
            if (sucess != nil){
                let value = headers.valueForKey("info")  as! String
                print("info: \(value)")
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sucessRequest", object: self)

            }
            else{
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("requestError2", object: self)

            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

How should I notify my main thread the result of the request?

Comment: Call dispatch async and step onto the main thread. What's the problem?

Comment: How should I call the dispatch async and step onto the main thread? The problem is that the postNotification sometimes fails and has some delay in run the observer.

Comment: The delay is because you did not do what I just said.

Comment: thanks I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly do you mean with main thread and if that is just a main thread (and not another controller or something similar) I think you should use closures that will get executed on main thread by using dispatch async.A function that described what I wrote would look similar like this :

```
func request(onSuccess : (value:String) -> Void, onError: ()->Void){

    let request1 = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: serverID)!)
    request1.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    for key in parameters.keys{
        request1.addValue(parameters[key] as String!, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
    }

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request1) {
        data, response1, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("request1Error", object: self)
            return
        }
        else {
            let httpResponse = response1 as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let headers = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as NSDictionary
            let sucess: AnyObject? = headers.objectForKey("UserId")
            if (sucess != nil){
                let value = headers.valueForKey("info")  as! String
                print("info: \(value)")

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                    onSuccess(value)
                })

            }
            else{

                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                    onError()
                  })
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The delay is due to the fact that you're trying use the `NSNotificationCenter` on the same thread that you're using `NSURLSession` on. Try updating your calls to the `NSNotificationCenter` with something along the lines of:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sucessRequest", object: self)
}
```